# Angularjs array of data sort to range

Tags: angularjs

I am having some sample array of data.

Eg:

```
var arr = ["test1#1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15,true,false", 
           "test2#1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15,true,false", 
           "test3#1,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15,true,false"].
```

If array of data number sequence match to range like more than two digits. I want to display above array of data as below.

```
     result = [
            {"test1","1-5,7,8,10-12,15",true,false},
            {"test2","1-3,5,7,9-12,15",true,false},
            {"test3","1,3-5,7,8,10-12,15",true,false}
        ].
```

How can I achieve this result using angularjs? Kindly help on this to sort of this.

Comment: It looks like homework, please show your tries, post relevant code snippets

Comment: to make an array of objects you should have key,value pairs, your target array is not valid objects you can't define an object like `{"test3","1,3-5,7,8,10-12,15",true,false}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need angularjs to do it.

You can do it using JavaScript only.

```js
var arr = ["test1#1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15,true,false", 
           "test2#1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15,true,false", 
           "test3#1,3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,15,true,false"];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   
    var test = arr[i].split("#");
    console.log(test[0]);
    var key = test[0];
    var value = test[1];
    result.push({key:value});

}

console.log(result);
```